# Expanding / Collapsing Modules in Wordpress Panel

Tags: plugins, javascript

I'm using WordPress 3.3.2. version. I can't able to expand / collapse modules in wordpress panel. I have deactivated all plugins and checked. But no result. 
If i disable Java Script, it is working well.

Can any one please give me a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Screen Options dropdown in the top right corner of your WordPress admin. Uncheck unwanted boxes.

If not, you likely have a javascript, jQuery, or php error somewhere.

Comment: No result when i click Screen Options. Nothing happening. Remains as it is.

Comment: You likely have a javascript error somewhere. Pan you past your page source or any javascript code you're using?

Comment: Sounds like you have a jQuery conflict caused by your theme.

Comment: Thanks, I found out my mistake. I blocked some scripts in functions.php. once i removed, its working well.

Comment: That's what I like to hear!